# Как удалить "\"?

Tags: javascript

```
var str="asdasd\\asdsa\\asd\\asd\\\\da";
var str2=str.replace(\,''); -не пашет
var str2=str.replace("\",''); -не пашет
var str2=str.replace('\',''); -не пашет
```

Никак не могу найти ответ, как удалить этот чертов "\", и не один, а все!

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что символ "\" (обратный слэш) - это управляющий символ, который используется для экранирования других управляющих символов, например, чтобы апостроф не закрывал строку:

```
var string = 'It\'s quite chilly today, isn\'t it?';
// It's quite chilly today, isn't it?
```

Впрочем, ситуация с обратным слэшем не отличается от ситуации с другими управляющими символами - достаточно его заэкранировать, и все станет на свои места!

```
var backslash = '\\';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/msj209c4/

Comment: Спасибо за расширенное дополнение :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй var str2=str.replace('\\','');